# redux-form wizard step validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, wizard

In the demo of the wizard form (https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/wizard/), if we fill it like this :

- fill the data of the first step;
- go to the second step;
- go back to the first step;
- go to the second step;
- all errors are displayed

I thought I could manage this aspect with « forceUnregisterOnUnmount » but apparently not.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: My guess is that the second page's form 'touches' its fields, so the error is displayed. You could try playing around with `redux-form`'s actions to unmark the fields as touched when going back a page.

Comment: `forceUnregisterOnUnmount` is so the form retains its state, so if it becomes `touched`, it will remain that.

Comment: keep the different name for both the forms

Comment: I suppose you can just change this line to whatever you like `{touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}`